# Filehandling with Python on Linux OS

Tags: python, linux

I have written the following code on Python on Linux OS:

```
 variable='jack'
 import os
 os.system('mkdir '+variable)
```

Then a directory is made with the name jack on the present working directory.

However, if I want to use file handling for the same purpose

```
variable='jack'
f=open('xyz.txt', mode="w")
f.write("import os")
f.write("os.system('mkdir '+variable)")
f.close()
```

then the code `os.system('mkdir '+variable)` is appended as it is in the `xyz.txt` file instead of `os.system('mkdir jack')`

Please help me to get this variable inside the file `xyz.txt`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the variable:

```
f.write("os.system(mkdir {})".format(variable))
```

or:

```
f.write("os.system(mkdir " + variable + ")"))
```

You are writing the literal string `"+ variable"` as you have it all inside the double quotes. You also have a problem with `f.write("import os")` as you added no newline so all your data would be on one line so if you plan on executing that code later add a newline `f.write("import os\n")` and remember to strip it off later if you are reading line by line.

So:

```
with open('xyz.txt', w) as f:
   f.write("import os\n")
   f.write("os.system(mkdir {})".format(variable))
```

If you plan on executing the code later, add single quotes around the name:

```
 f.write("os.system('mkdir {}')".format(variable))
```

You can also forget using system at all and just use [os.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir):

```
  with open('xyz.txt', w) as f:
       f.write("import os\n")
       f.write("os.mkdir('{}')".format(variable))
```

If you want to execute later:

```
with open('xyz.txt') as f:
   exec(f.read())
```